# pd.concat(array).groupby('date').sum() returns unexpected behavior

Tags: python, pandas

I have 8 dataframes of the same length, with a "date" column that looks the same across all (though I don't use it as index).

```
>>> _dataframes[0].tail(3)

            date  trade_number
4122  2019-07-15           678
4123  2019-07-16           678
4124  2019-07-17           678
```

They all end at index `4124` with date `2019-07-17` and have a column `trade_number` with a value that's variable but it's always sorted in ascending order.

```
max = 0
for df in _dataframes:
    max += df ["trade_number"].max()
```

this gives `max = 4231`, consistent to what I find if I open a calculator and sum the last rows of every dataframe manually.

However...

```
>>> test = pd.concat(_dataframes).groupby("date", as_index=False).sum()
>>> test.tail(10)

            date  trade_number
4115  2019-07-08          4218
4116  2019-07-09          4219
4117  2019-07-10          4221
4118  2019-07-11          4223
4119  2019-07-12          4224
4120  2019-07-13          4224
4121  2019-07-14          4224
4122  2019-07-15          4230
4123  2019-07-16          4230
4124  2019-07-17          4512 # <--- WHY?
```

How come the last line reading is `2019-07-17 4512`. Why isn't that `4231`?

[Here's](https://privatebin.net/?381f12dbd714976c#DismWRgE4jmTwfcYnbuQzibk86s7kxiL4UjXKzuE66y7) the data that results from `pd.concat(_dataframes).to_clipboard()` so that you can import it with `pd.read_clipboard()`.

Comment: You should check `df.groupby('date').agg(len)`, your last date has an extra item. One of your DataFrames has probably a duplicate `2019-07-17`, which is why you see the difference

Comment: Can you produce a smaller dataset that exhibits the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: You are right: the error is in my data, I have a duplicate row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us check two things

```
pd.concat(_dataframes).groupby("date", as_index=False).date.nunique()
```

And

```
pd.concat(_dataframes).groupby("date", as_index=False).date.count()
```

If they are not equal , then when you do groupby you will have the different output

Since the for loop , will only sum the max value , not all the value . To match with the output

```
pd.concat(_dataframes).sort_values('trade_number').drop_duplicates('date',keep='last').groupby('date')['trade_number'].sum()
```